# cannot convert from 'cv::Scalar_<double>' to 'cv::Mat'

Tags: c++

I'm trying to replicate the [Canny Edge detector](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html) sample in one of my programs and I ran into this issue. I believe this is a general C++ question rather than a specific one for openCV (version used 2.4.9).

If I try to compile this it fails with an error:

```
        cv::Mat dst = cv::Scalar::all(0);
```

Error:

```
Error   1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'cv::Scalar_<double>' to 'cv::Mat'
```

But, it works if I try to compile with this:

```
        cv::Mat dst;
        dst = cv::Scalar::all(0);
```

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the first syntax

```
cv::Mat dst = cv::Scalar::all(0);
```

is actually calling a constructor and initializing (to be precise, it tries to call a copy-constructor). On the other hand, this syntax

```
cv::Mat dst;
dst = cv::Scalar::all(0);
```

calls an assignment operator, which is [perfectly defined when scalar is on the right side](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-operator).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fill your matrix with zeros you may also consider:

```
cv::Mat dst = Mat(1,1, CV_64F, cvScalar(0.));
```

OR

```
cv::Mat dst;
dst= Mat::zeros(1, 1, CV_64F);
```

Hope that helps!